# Change color and size of Textview in custom Listview having custom adapter and custom layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am having problem with changing color of Textview in custom Listview.

My xml file is column.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cid"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cname"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="#f60505" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#2ec31d"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and ListViewAdapter.java goes like this

```
package accounts.com.accountbook;

import static accounts.com.accountbook.Constants.FIRST_COLUMN;
import static accounts.com.accountbook.Constants.SECOND_COLUMN;
import static accounts.com.accountbook.Constants.THIRD_COLUMN;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by XYZ on 06-05-2016.
 */
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;
    Activity activity;
    TextView txtFirst;
    TextView txtSecond;
    TextView txtThird;



    public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>list){
        super();
        this.activity=activity;
        this.list=list;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null){

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.colunm_row,null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.textFirst=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cid);
            holder.textSecond=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cname);
            holder.textThird=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.amt);

            txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cid);
            txtSecond = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cname);
            txtThird = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.amt);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder =(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            holder.textFirst.setText("");
            holder.textSecond.setText("");
            holder.textThird.setText("");
        }

        HashMap<String,String> map= list.get(position);
      /*  txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
        txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
        txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));*/


        holder.textFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
        holder.textSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
        holder.textThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));

        return convertView;
    }


    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView textFirst;
        TextView textSecond;
        TextView textThird;
    }
}
```

DisplayActivity :

```
package accounts.com.accountbook;
import static accounts.com.accountbook.Constants.FIRST_COLUMN;
import static accounts.com.accountbook.Constants.SECOND_COLUMN;
import static accounts.com.accountbook.Constants.THIRD_COLUMN;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AccDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arrayList;
    Cursor c;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DBHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_acc_display);

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.AcclistView);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("AccountsDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);


        c=db.rawQuery("select c.c_id ,c.c_name, ((select CASE WHEN (sum(cr.amount)) IS Null THEN 0 ELSE sum(cr.amount) END from credit_master cr where c.c_id=cr.c_id) ) - ((select CASE WHEN (sum(d.amount)) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE sum(d.amount) END from debit_master d where c.c_id = d.c_id ) ) as Tot from customers c ORDER BY c.c_name ASC",null);
        //c=db.rawQuery("select c.c_id ,c.c_name, ((select sum(cr.amount) from credit_master cr where c.c_id=cr.c_id) ) - ((select sum(d.amount) from debit_master d where c.c_id = d.c_id ) ) as Tot from customers c",null);
        try {
            if (c!=null){
                if(c.moveToFirst()){
                    Map<String,String> tem  = new HashMap<String ,String>();
                    tem.clear();
                    arrayList.clear();
                    listView.setAdapter(null);
                    int cnt = c.getCount();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+cnt,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    do {

                        tem = new HashMap<String,String>();
                        tem.clear();

                        tem.put(FIRST_COLUMN, c.getString(0));
                        tem.put(SECOND_COLUMN,c.getString(1));
                        tem.put(THIRD_COLUMN,c.getString(2));
                        arrayList.add((HashMap<String, String>) tem);
                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error"+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this,arrayList);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                TextView tv = (TextView) (view.findViewById(R.id.cid));

                int str = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString());

                Toast.makeText(AccDisplay.this,"Clicked"+str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               Intent intent = new Intent(AccDisplay.this,Details.class);
                intent.putExtra("name",str);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }



    protected void onRestart(){
        super.onRestart();
        Intent inte = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(inte);
    }
}
```

I am using same layout file for three different activities.

I want to display different color of each TextView in Different Activity.

I have tried this but didn't work

```
    LayoutInflator inflator  = (LayoutInflator)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATOR_SERVICE);

View vi = inflator.inflate(R.layout.column,null);

TextView tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.amt);

tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

I can change color of TextView in OnItemClickListener but i want to display color while displaying data.

I am having Debit/Credit activity which uses same Adapter class and column.xml layout for displaying data in listview.

I want to display TextView1 in black color font and TextView2 in Green color with big font size in Activity 1. and different color in different activity.

Comment: You don't need to do this in Program. Have you though of Setting the color in the XML itself with android:textColor="@color/Black"

Comment: I have already given green color to one TextView. But i want to display different color in different activity as i am re-using the layout file.

Comment: Ok, may be you can pass an `ArrayList` of colors to the adapter. so add different colors from the `Activity`.

Comment: @Vishal Solanki Can you re-edit the above code with the code snippet for updating the TextView. Coz I cant figure out this way why this code is going wrong. Just update the above code of ListViewAdapter with the color changing implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can pass different flags in adapter constructor to adapter for identifying activity if same adapter you are using for other activities, and can put conditions according to the flag set colors to the TextView in adapter programmatically. textView.setTextColor(put_your_color);